# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'buildTransaction'

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3.py

Im trying to send a transaction to contract function with web3.py on ropsten testnet. while doing so, Im getting this error.

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'buildTransaction'

here is my web3.py transaction signing code

```
tx = contract_instance.greet("Hi devs").buildTransaction({'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_address)})
# Get tx receipt to get contract address
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, key)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

please let me know what seems to be the problem. full code here https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hMUP.jpg

Comment: Well, you could by the least indicate which line of code throws this exception (we're not supposed to guess that). In addition, we have no way of (yet again) guessing the values of some of the variables in your code, for example, `account_address`, `key` and `tx_hash`. Please spend some time rewriting your question properly, including all the required information!

Comment: What version of `web3.py` are you using? I suspect you're mixing syntax from different versions. The error indicates that `contract_instance.greet(...)` is returning a `list`. In the latest version of `web3.py`, you would use something like `contract_instance.functions.greet(...).buildTransaction(...)`. (Note the `.functions.`)

Comment: Oh, looking at your full code in the screenshot, `ConciseContract` may be the issue. Use the default factory instead and then use `contract_instance.functions.greet(...).buildTransaction(...)`. And in the future, please post your full code directly rather than as a screenshot. Images are not searchable/copy-pastable/accessible.